# Use VBA to copy unique rows to another spreadsheet if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm new to VBA and any help would be greatly appreciated!!

My office is coordinating applications for positions across the US. When people apply, they pick which two states they would be willing to work in. All application information is manually entered into Worksheet A, which has a lot of columns, but 5 important ones: Unique ID, First Name, Last Name, Preferred State1, Preferred State2. This worksheet gets updated daily.

I have 50 worksheets (one for each state in the US). I wrote VBA code to copy each row from Spreadsheet A into the 50 state worksheets when the state worksheet is created.

I need to copy the new information that is added to Spreadsheet A every day into the appropriate state spreadsheets. All applicants who picked a state need to go into the state worksheet (the state order of preference doesn't matter).

For example, today, Spreadsheet A could be:

| ID | First Name | Last Name | State1 | State2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Bob | Belcher | New Jersey | Alaska |
| 222 | Rose | Nylund | Minnesota | Florida |
| 333 | Beef | Tobin | Alaska | California |

So the Alaska spreadsheet would have:

| ID | First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Bob | Belcher |
| 333 | Beef | Tobin |

Tomorrow, Worksheet A could have new people added (IDs 444 and 555) and I would only want to add the new people who picked Alaska to the Alaska worksheet (ID 555 Colin Robinson).

| ID | First Name | Last Name | State1 | State2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Bob | Belcher | New Jersey | Alaska |
| 222 | Rose | Nylund | Minnesota | Florida |
| 333 | Beef | Tobin | Alaska | California |
| 444 | Charlie | Bucket | New York | Florida |
| 555 | Colin | Robinson | New York | Alaska |

I was using this code based on unique IDs in Column A, but it doesn't account for the different states.

```
Sub Copy ()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = Sheet4
Set sh2 = Sheet1
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("B2:B" & lr)
For Each c In rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh2.Range("B:B"), c.Value) = 0 Then
        sh2.Range("B" & sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)(2).Resize(1, 5) = c.Resize(1, 5).Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we assume that the `ID` will always be a unique number? I have seen similar examples where there would be a column to flag the copied data with a string e.g. `Copied`, `Transferred` or `Yes`... Maybe you could consider this change for the code to be more efficient and you would immediately see if all data was transferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export Data to Multiple Worksheets

- To avoid creating duplicates, I've added a 6th (`sfrCol`) flag column which will contain `"Yes"` (`sFlag`) in each row that was transferred. The code is just looking for any content, so you can use whatever value you like.
- The code will first find the first available cell in this flag column to reference the range of data that was not transferred.
- Then it will loop through the rows of this range and transfer (copy) the rows accordingly, creating new worksheets, if necessary, otherwise, appending the rows after the already written data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportByCountry()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "A" ' Worksheet Name
    Const slrCol As Long = 1 ' Last Row Column
    Const sfrCol As Long = 6 ' Flag Column
    Const sFlag As String = "Yes"
    Dim stCols As Variant: stCols = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3) ' Transfer Columns
    Dim scCols As Variant: scCols = VBA.Array(4, 5) ' Country Columns
    ' Destination
    Const dfCol As Long = 1 ' First Column
    Const dfRow As Long = 1 ' First Row
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim stUpper As Long: stUpper = UBound(stCols)
    Dim scUpper As Long: scUpper = UBound(scCols)
    Dim dtCount As Long: dtCount = stUpper + 1
    Dim dHeaders As Variant: ReDim dHeaders(0 To stUpper)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    Dim dt As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' (with headers)
        ' Write headers to an array.
        For dt = 0 To stUpper
            dHeaders(dt) = .Cells(dt + 1).Value
        Next dt
        srCount = .Rows.Count
        ' Reference the source data range (no headers)
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
     
    Dim sfCell As Range
    s
    ' Reference the first available cell in the flag column ('sfCell').
    With srg.Columns(sfrCol)
        Set sfCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If sfCell Is Nothing Then
            Set sfCell = .Cells(1)
        ElseIf sfCell.Row = srCount Then
            MsgBox "Data already transferred.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set sfCell = sfCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Reference the not flagged range ('srg').
    Set srg = srg.Resize(srCount - sfCell.Row + 1).Offset(sfCell.Row - 2)
    srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Write the range to the source array ('sData').
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    Dim dtData As Variant: ReDim dtData(0 To stUpper) ' Transfer Data Array
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim drrg As Range ' Destination Row Range
    Dim sr As Long ' Source Row Counter
    Dim sc As Long ' Source Country Column Counter
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        For sc = 0 To scUpper
            ' Attempt to create a reference to the destination worksheet.
            On Error Resume Next
                Set dws = wb.Worksheets(sData(sr, scCols(sc)))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If dws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet doesn't exist
                ' Add a new worksheet, rename it and write the headers.
                Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
                dws.Name = sData(sr, scCols(sc))
                dws.Cells(dfRow, dfCol).Resize(, dtCount).Value = dHeaders
            'Else ' worksheet exists; do nothing
            End If
            ' Write the values from the row ('sr') of the source array
            ' to the transfer data array.
            For dt = 0 To stUpper
                dtData(dt) = sData(sr, stCols(dt))
            Next dt
            ' Reference the first 'available' destination row range.
            With dws.Columns(dfCol)
                Set drrg = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious) _
                    .Offset(1).Resize(, dtCount)
            End With
            ' Write the values from the transfer data array
            ' to the destinaton row range.
            drrg.Value = dtData
            
            Set dws = Nothing
        Next sc
        ' Write the flag.
        srg.Cells(sr, sfrCol).Value = sFlag
    Next sr
    
    sws.Select
    'wb.Save
    
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ran the code and got a debug message: "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Name' of object'_Worksheet' failed and the row that gets highlighted is dws.Name = sData(sr, scCols(sc)) 

I also don't know if it matters, but I have another column with email between Last Name and State1.

Comment: `stCols` represents the columns to be copied in this case `1,2,3` means `A,B,C`. `scCols` represents the country columns in this case `4,5` means `D,E`. So if you have something else in the columns you need to conclude what to do. If the emails are in column `D` i.e. column `4`, then `4` is not available so you will use `5,6` if the country columns are `E,F`. Also, I said that I added a column for the flag. Make it the last column. So if you don't have any more columns then you will do `Const sfrCol As Long = 7`. You could remove all the country worksheets and see how they are created.

Comment: I did that and I think the problem is that not everyone picked 2 countries. Some people only picked 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it if the only macro I wanted was to be in Spreadsheet A and you just wanted to use copy-paste to transfer data versus sql.

Note: The items below with a *, you can record a macro to generate the code for you and paste it in your function to cobble together the code pretty quickly.

1. First set ScreenUpdating=false to eliminate the screen from
   flashing.
2. Create an array of the state names to loop through.
3. In the loop, apply a filter to the spreadsheet to reduce the rows to just one's that match the current "state"*
4. Open the other file - be sure to name the file with the state name so you can reference the filename with the array.  (see Workbooks.Open)
5. Paste by inserting rows at A1* of the state spreadsheet.
6. Select All and do a menu option Data-->Remove Duplicates*

If you have data that makes #6 a problem, then there will be some more code required to check for existing.

See ya,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

In the For loop before the If, add

```
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(c.Offset(, 3).Value2)
```

This requires that the values in the State columns exactly matches the state sheet names

To process the second state repeat the Set and If block, using `Offset(, 4)`

If this code is too slow, consider switching to a Variant Array approach